# MS Test Default Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have a solution that contains several class library projects, and a test project for each class library project.

When I right-click a method and select Create Unit Tests, the Create Unit Tests dialog pre-selects a test project I have not worked with in a long time (it was the first one added to the solution).

Is there a way to change the default test project so that I don't have to change that setting every time?